# JQuery Mobile DateBox - more than 1 instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile Datebox as I am having the following problem.

I have page A and page B.

If I go to page B and open the date picker called "date2", then close it and click the Home page link, which goes to page A.

Now, I'm in page a and I hit the button to open up date picker A, called "date" ...

The problem is that I'm getting both opening ... it's like they are both opened or something.

How can I kill the instance of the date pickers once closed please?

Here's the relevant code for page A:

In the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function(){
            $.mobile.page.prototype.options.degradeInputs.date = 'text';
        }); 
    </script>
```

Then the form / date picker 1:

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" style="visibility:hidden;">
          <input value="" name="date" type="date" data-role="datebox" id="date" data-theme="a" data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "pickPageTheme": "a", "pickPageHighButtonTheme": "e", "setDateButtonLabel": "Calendar", "useDialogForceTrue": false, "useDialogForceFalse": true }'/>   


          </div>
          </form>
```

Now the relevant code for page B

in the page head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function(){
            $.mobile.page.prototype.options.degradeInputs.date = 'text';
        }); 
    </script>

<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

       var queryDate = $.url.param("mydate");
       $('#date2').val(queryDate);


    });

</script>
```

And the form part:

```
<form action="save.php" method="POST">

          <label for="date2" style="margin:10px 0px;">Event Date:</label>
          <input value="1/1/2011" name="date2" type="date" data-role="datebox" id="date2" data-theme="a" data-options='{"pickPageTheme": "a", "pickPageHighButtonTheme": "e", "setDateButtonLabel": "Add Date", "dateFormat": "dd/mm/YYYY"}'/>  

          <label for="textarea">Add:</label>
                <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" data-theme="a" />


          </form>
```

Anyone has any clues please?

Thanks

Comment: Satch3000 for most of your questions please add code that you are trying as it's very hard to determine what exactly is going on

Comment: From my understanding (And I could be wrong) all your JS should be in the main page and not on each individual page

Comment: I'm using multiple pages that's why I 'm doing it this way.

Comment: So are you transitioning to the page or does it open a new page?

Comment: Yes, I transition from page A to B and visa versa. They are actually different pages. Example: pageA.html , pageB.html etc

Comment: ok so try adding the JS from page B to page A and remove it from page B. If you're transitioning the page is loaded into the DOM and (again I could be wrong) not sure if you can load more JS with jQM this way. I've always added all my JS to the main index (root page) for all my pages

Comment: Ref: I've always added all my JS to the main index (root page) for all my pages .... even if the pages are separate pages? So, if I create a variable on pageA pageB will be able to read it without posting it over?

Comment: Yep, as I understand it, it's all in the DOM

Comment: But will this make a difference? The main problem is that I option 2 instances of the calendar. So, I option the first one and then close it...then I open the second one and they both come out ... If claendar 1 instance was to be killed when I closed it, wouldn't that fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jquery mobile do not use document.ready() for jqm. it will not work. use something like this instead. 
check out the jqm demo for the full list of events. [Demo](http://jquerymobile.com/test/)

```
 $(document).live('pageshow',function() {

       var queryDate = $.url.param("mydate");
       $('#date2').val(queryDate);


    });
```

Also all js should be in the first html that is loaded. in your case it's page A.
Simply because the subsequent page is loaded via ajax and js that is written inside will not be executed.